# How do you read a file name from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

I build the following table (it adds yesterday's 8 digit date to some text):

```
create table DayBefore as select (current_date -interval '1 Days')::timestamp::text;
update daybefore set text = substr (text, 1, 10);
update daybefore set text = replace (text, '-', '');
update daybefore set text = 'MyFile_'||text;
```

and I can do:

```
select * from daybefore;

text
---------------------------------
 MyFile_20170126
(1 row)
```

You'll understand that if the associated script runs daily, this resulting entry also changes daily.

My question is:  How do I now refer to the ***table*** `MyFile_20170126` in a following command ie

`select * from 'MyFile_????????'` or `create table my_table as select * from MyFile_????????`

Going batty on this now and I can't upgrade the version of PostgreSQL from 8.2 either :-s

Any help greatly appreciated ... !

Comment: Why not have *one* table with a date *column*. 99% of the time this is the correct approach.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html). That, and dynamic SQL, which depends entirely on how you're running the SQL: a pl/pgsql function? from PHP? from a command-line script using `psql`?

Comment: Also, your date format manipulation can all be done by [the `to_char` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html). I think the format you want is `'MyFile_' || to_char(current_date -interval '1 Days', 'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you *really* have a table, which is called `MyFile_20170126`? Or you have (somewhere) a `MyFile_20170126` named file, which is some kind of export of a table (CSV f.ex.)?

Comment: Very little of your question makes sense. Whats the name of your table. What's the name of the field, and what are the values in that field. What you are trying to select from that table/field?

Comment: Hi All and thanks for your comments ... Alex-K - I'm reading a table that's set by another program so I can't change any details.  I'm reading the entire table so field names are irrelevant.

Comment: Hi All and thanks for your comments ... Alex-K - I'm reading a table that's set by another program so I can't change any details.  JNevill - I'm reading the entire table so field names are irrelevant.  POZS - yes, I have a table called MyFile_YYYYMMDD.  IMSoP - Dynamic SQL beyond me I'm afraid, also to_char function does not appear to work BUT I am trying to end up with           [create table TEMP1 as select * FROM 'MyFile_'|| to_char(current_date -interval '1 Days', 'YYYYMMDD')] ...

Comment: create table Temp_Store as
select  * FROM ('MyFile_' || to_char(current_date -interval '1 Days', 'YYYYMMDD'))
 host_table.fqdn AS "Src_FQDN"
 from MyFile_YYYYMMDD left outer join host_table
 on MyFile_YYYYMMDD.src_ip = host(host_table.ip)

Comment: Sorry All - that looks confusing ... I am trying to read everything from a table that has as part of its name the date in the format YYYYMMDD, and I need to do it for yesterday's date eg if today is 30 Jan '17, then I am trying to select * from MyFile_20170129 - and I need to do this programmatically from psql on a daily basis.  I can not upgrade from V8.2 .  I have been unable to use to_char so far (don't know why but I get no usable value returned).  I can build the table name in another temporary table but I then can't work out how to get it back to use it to read the table of that name.

Comment: HELP!!!!!!!  `wglog=# select * FROM 'MyFile_'|| to_char(current_date -interval '1 Days', 'YYYYMMDD') limit 10;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'MyFile_'"
LINE 1: select * FROM 'MyFile_'|| to_char(current_date -interval '1 ...`